# Has anyone implemented a function to calculate the direction of solar radiation?

Tags: python, trigonometry, azimuth, solar

I want to calculate the direction of solar radiation for every hour (that the sun is up) in the Netherlands in 2017, 2018 and 2019. I'm doing a research about the generation of solar panels, and I think this feature would add a lot to my models.

I found a few formula's to calculate the direction of solar radiation and was wondering if anyone ever implemented these in Python.

```
H = arcsine(sin(psi)sin(D) - cos(psi)cos(D)cos(U))  = solar altitude

A = arcsine{(cos(D)sin(U))/cos(H)}   = azimuth
```

where

```
psi = latitude on earth

D = 23,44*sin{360*(284 + n)/365}  = declination  with n = n-th day of the year

U = t * 15  = local hour angle with t = t-th hour of the day
```

So I'm interested in H. I know it is supposed to look like this:
[Azimuth and solar altitude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR4nh.png)

Has anyone ever implemented something like this in Python?

Comment: This isn't a programming question but rather a mathematical question. It _may_ be more appropriate on the [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) but the fact that you're writing it in Python is tangential to your real question

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question

Comment: Have you tried [astropy](https://www.astropy.org/)? I think it has all the functions you need - calculating Sun's position in equatorial coordinates and transforming equatorial coordinates to azimuthal.

Comment: Just to expand on the previous comments, all these functions you describe in your formulas exist in Python as built-ins under the `math` module. For instance, `math.sin(360*(284 + n)/365)` is a real function. But this is more a mathematical problem which other people are more qualified to answer. Also, **questions regarding "does this library exists" is generally not allowed on SO** as they are easily answered by using any popular search engine, and if you can't find it neither can we (usually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly a vast number of packages you can find which already do that such as [SunPy](https://docs.sunpy.org/en/stable/api/sunpy.coordinates.get_sun_orientation.html?highlight=zenith) or [Astropy](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.coordinates.get_sun.html?highlight=sun).

Comment: Hi! I found Pysolar because of your advice! Works very well to append direction of solar radiation with only the date (and time). Thanks a lot. My very first stackoverflow problem solved :)